# Give arguments to generic eventhandler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a bunch of elements with a generic onclick event like

```
function foo( i , j ) {
   alert("foo");
   //dostuff 
};

for (i = 1; i < 8; i++){
  var clas = get_class_for_index( i );
  for ( j = 0; j < 96; j++){

     // tbody > #(i) is a <tr>
     $("#table > tbody > #" + i ).append( function(){
         // I want to give ( i , j ) to foo
         return $("<td id='" + j + "' class='" + clas + "'></td>").on("click", foo );
     });

  };
};
```

So, how could I give these arguments to foo? I could also use the IDs of  and  due they're (i,j) but how do I get them from inside foo?

Comment: .("click", foo(i,j) ) doesn't work???

Comment: No, due foo(i,j) will call foo immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use closure with IIFE here, otherwise because of the scoping you will end up passing the last iterated value of `i or j` to the event handler.

***Something like this***:

```js
var $anchors = $("a");

function foo(idx) {
   alert("foo " + idx);
};

for(var i = 0; i < $anchors.length; i++) {
    $anchors.eq(i).on("click", (function(i) {
        return function(e) {
            foo(i);
        }
    }(i)));    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Link</a> | <a href="#">Link</a> | <a href="#">Link</a> | <a href="#">Link</a>
```

In the above example, we are using a function that is immediately executed (with `i` as a parameter) and returns a function which will then be bound as the click handler and pass the correct `i` to your `foo`. This is called an IIFE (immediately-inoked function expression).

Comment: Nice use of closure.. :)

Comment: Like a baws! This one should be learned by anyone who doesn't know.

Answer (score 1):

> **Can I pass parameters to event Handler?**

No you cant. The event handler function executes when the event occurs, You are not calling `foo()` to pass `i` and `j`, `foo()` will get executed even after for loop execution finishes and there will not be any existence of `i` & `j`.

> **Then What can I do in my condition.**

The best way is add i and j values to DOM element itself so you can access it in event handler function. You can use data() method of jQuery to add extra information to DOM.

```
function foo(evt) {
  $(evt.currentTarget).data() //You will get here all values, i.e. i & j
    //dostuff 
};

for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
  var clas = get_class_for_index(i);
  for (j = 0; j < 96; j++) {

    // tbody > #(i) is a <tr>
    $("#table > tbody > #" + i).append(function() {
      // I want to give ( i , j ) to foo
      return $("<td id='" + j + "' class='" + clas + "'></td>").data({
        i: i,
        j: j
      }).on("click", foo);
    });

  };
};
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/sfxax4nc/) is updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery `on` function in order to register the event to the element once created, you can use the Id of the element to attach the event to it and call the foo in the event callback function.

I have added a working snipped that used a combined id with i and j as follows

```js
function foo( i , j ) {
       console.log(i+"_"+j);
       alert(i+"_"+j);
       //dostuff 
    };
    
    for (i = 1; i < 8; i++){
      var clas = "aa_"+i;
      
       $("#table").append("<tr id='" + i + "'></tr>");
         
      for ( j = 0; j < 96; j++){
    
         // tbody > #(i) is a <tr>

         $("#table > tbody > #" + i ).append( function(){
             // I want to give ( i , j ) to foo
             return $("<td id='test_" + i + "_" + j + "' class='" + clas + "'>aa</td>").on("click",    function(){
               
               
               var id = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
               //console.log(id);
               foo(id[1],id[2]);
           } );
         });
    
      };
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Got a typo in my question, .on was missing. Basicly, this is exactly what i tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sempie check the edit, this might be useful for you.

Answer (score -2):

When using event handler you may use .on() of jquery for the event handler like this example.

```
$("#id").on("click", function(){   
  //do stuff here or call a function; 
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Got a typo in my question, .on    was missing. Basicly, this is exactly what i tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try return the div with `.setAttribute("onclick", "foo(i,j)");` instead of `.on('click', foo);`

Comment: wouldn't work either due i,j are loop incrementals, not fixed values.